# Can my google news sitemap be blank?

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

I have my google news sitemap, which according to google's spec, should contain articles posted in last 2 days. Now, suppose there are no articles pushed in last 2 days for my site, my news sitemap would be empty. IS this the desired behaviour. Do I need to show something else, if no articles are posted in last 2 days. Will the webmaster tools invalidate the sitemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what other choice there is for a sitemapper if you have not created any news stories within last two days. You could perhaps choose not to update your news sitemap? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Will the webmaster tools invalidate the sitemap?

Yes, it will... But then, GWT judges it as any regular xml sitemap and does not account for specific Google News sitemap rules.

So the more important question is:

> IS this the desired behaviour. Do I need to show something else, if no
>   articles are posted in last 2 days.

... to which I cannot find any clear answer anywhere :(